# File Not Found Exception While writing into the file

Tags: android

```
try {
        File myFile = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + fileName);

        BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));
        buf.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        buf.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File Not Found"+fileName,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"IOException",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: 1) you are not writing, you are reading file. 2) you are likely missing `/` between `android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` and `fileName`. `File` has constructor with 2 `String` parameters, first one is the directory, 2nd - file name. You can use it if you have separate path and name

Comment: As @VladyslavMatviienko already stated, you are not writing - `buf.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);`

Comment: Tq bro....I got my answer